# BelongsToMany relationship with use of with

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have an N: N relationship that is giving me a problem with the return using `with()` follows the example of my two models with a problem and the way I make the query call.

Model product_type

```
public function makes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Make::class);
}
```

Model make

```
public function productTypes()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ProductType::class);
}
```

My relationship table has the following fields

```
make_product_type -> nome da tabela
make_id
product_type_id
```

In my controller I'm trying to return all products with their brands in this way

```
Make::with('productTypes')->get()
```

but at this point the following error is returned:

**Trying to get property 'make_id' of non-object**

I've tried to inform the relationship fields in the model but it didn't work either. The only way it worked was by overriding the model's toArray () method and forcing the relationship to return, which for me is not feasible since I only need to return this relationship in a query that is executed.

```
public function toArray()
{
    return [
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
       'product_type' => $this->productTypes()->get()->toArray()
     ];
}
```

If anyone can explain to me what I am doing wrong and especially why it is wrong I would be very grateful, as I have read the Laravel documentation several times and I have not been successful in understanding what the problem is. Obs. If there is a suggestion to change the table structure there is also no problem because I am starting a project and at this moment I can still change things

**Edit**

follow my migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('make_product_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('make_id')->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreignId('product_type_id')->constrained() 
             ->onDelete('restrict');
        });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('make_product_type');
}
```

My table only has these records that I inserted for testing

```
|make_id             |product_type_id     |
|--------------------|--------------------|
|1                   |1                   |
|1                   |2                   |
|1                   |18                  |
```

Make Migration

```
Schema::create('makes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->integer('importance')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('deleted_by')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Product Migration

```
Schema::create('product_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('deleted_by')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Resolved**

```
I managed to find the problem, I had a function to set the attributes
public function setAttribute ($key, $value)
{
    if (array_key_exists ($key, $this->columns)) {
        $key = $this->columns [$key];
     }
         return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}

I dont understand why but when removing this function everything worked normally.
Thank you very much for the help you have given me
```

Comment: dd this line Make::with('productTypes')->get() and see whats inside

Comment: if you change the method name as product_types which means to follow laravel convention and dd the result. what you see than?

Comment: @miladhp The error returned is the same: Trying to get property 'make_id' of non-object

Comment: @NaveedAli Changing the method name to product_types and also calling it with the return is the same error

Comment: i guess in your pivot table you have a product_type_id that its product_type is deleted!
so laravel has an id of one product_type but it is deleted from that table! 
i think it is your problem check this again

Comment: the error is like you are missing a record. try to delete the records and then insert it again propoerly

Comment: I cleared the table and inserted only 3 records for testing and continued the same error

Answer (score 0):

It works as you wanted

**make_product_type migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('make_product_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('make_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('make_id')->references('id')->on('makes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_type_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('product_type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('make_product_type');
}
```

**Model product_type**

```
public function makes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Make');
}
```

**Model Make**

```
public function productTypes()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductType');
}
```

Then check in your controller

```
$products = Make::with('productTypes')->get();
dd($products);
```

Comment: so the error returned is as follows: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "make_make"

Comment: Show your migration in your question

Comment: there is a problem in your migration

Comment: added migration and table structure

Comment: `$table->foreignId('make_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');`  and  `$table->foreignId('product_type_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: I made the changes but the error persists in the same way

Comment: Can you show `make migration` and `product migration`?

Comment: added migrations as requested

Comment: I edited my answer. You change `make_product_type migration` as my answer

Answer (score 0):

first you need add

```
public function up(){

    Schema::create('make_product_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('make_id')->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreignId('product_type_id')->constrained() 
             ->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->primary(['make_id', 'product_type_id']);
        });
}
```

thin add now model name is makeProductType

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class MakeProductType extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'make_product_type';

    protected $fillable = ['make_id', 'product_type_id'];

    protected $primaryKey = ['make_id', 'product_type_id'];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function makes() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class,'make_id','id');
    }

    public function ProductTypes() {

        return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class,'product_type_id','id');
    }

}
```

thin in model ProductType add new relationship

```
public function makeProductType(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MakeProductType::class, Make::class);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @abdulmajeed but you are returning this error now Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column makes.make_id